# How to assign the elements to different subsets according to the number of letter "A" within the element in R?

Tags: r, list, grouping

I want to assign my data into different groups depends on the number of letters "A".
For example,

```
library("stringr")
data1 <- c("apple","appreciate","available","account","adapt")
data2 <- c("tab","banana","cable","tatabox")
list1 <- list(data1,data2)
ca <- lapply(list1, function(x) str_count(x, "a"))
> ca
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 1 3 1 2
```

And I want to separate it like this way:

```
a1
[[1]]
[1] "apple" "account" 
[[2]]
[1] "tab" "cable"

a2
[[1]]
[1] "appreciate" "adapt"
[[2]]
[1] "tatabox"

a3 ....
```

Could you give me a hint that how can I do that? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easily done with `mapply`. But you have to set argument `SIMPLIFY = FALSE`, the default is `TRUE` and it returns a `matrix`.
Then, `unlist` the result and `split` again, this time by the `names` attribute of the resulting list.

```
ma <- mapply(split, list1, ca, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
tmp <- unlist(ma, recursive = FALSE)
pattern <- ".*\\.([[:digit:]]+)\\s*$"
replace <- "\\1"
split(tmp, sub(pattern, replace, names(tmp)))
#$`1`
#$`1`$`1`
#[1] "apple"   "account"
#
#$`1`$`1`
#[1] "tab"   "cable"
#
#
#$`2`
#$`2`$`2`
#[1] "appreciate" "adapt"     
#
#$`2`$`2`
#[1] "tatabox"
#
#
#$`3`
#$`3`$`3`
#[1] "available"
#
#$`3`$`3`
#[1] "banana"
```

Finally, clean up after yourself:

```
rm(tmp)
```

**Explanation.**

The `mapply` is explained above. Try running it without argument `SIMPLIFY` and see what is the result.
Then `unlist`. This is because `mapply` was applied to a list, the result of `split` and `ma` is a list of lists. If it becomes a simple list all strings of all members of `data1`, data2`, etc, are at the same list level.

Now the last `split`. Since the vector of `names(tmp)` is not a vector of counts of the target letter `"a"` but can be more complex than that, use a [regex](http://127.0.0.1:23221/library/base/html/regex.html) to keep just the counts.

The counts are the last digits after the last period `"."` and before the end of the string of names.

```
pattern <- ".*\\.([[:digit:]]+)\\s*$"
```

1. `.`    any character;
2. `.*`   any character repeated any number of times, zero or more;
3. `\\.`  the period, escaped with `\\` because it's a special character;
4. `(something)`  the parenthesis create a group, in this case the first group;
5. `[[:digit:]]`  the portable character class of decimal digits;
6. `[[:digit:]]+` the digits repeated one or more times;
7. `([[:digit:]]+)`  the group is at least one digit, maybe more;
8. `\\s*` blank space repeated zero or more times (maybe no spaces at all);
9. `$` end of string.

Seen from the end of the string, this is

1. `([[:digit:]]+)\\s*$` one or more digits, maybe followed by spaces, just before the end of the string;
2. `\\.([[:digit:]]+)\\s*$`  there is a period, `\\.`, just before the pattern in point 1.
3. `.*\\.([[:digit:]]+)\\s*$`  this can be preceded by any characters repeated any number of times.

The replacement is `\\1` a match of the group defined above. This means that only the group, the last digits after the last period, will make it to the result.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. But I have one more question when the list has a name then this code would not work. You can try this data:data1 <- c("apple","appreciate","available","account","adapt")
data2 <- c("tab","banana","cable","tatabox","aaaaaaa","aaaaaaaaaaa")
list1 <- list(data1,data2)
names(list1) <- c("adsf","bfds") Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @Codezy Done, I think. It was just the last code line that needed to be fixed. It now removes all non-digit characters, leaving the split factor with the counts only, before splitting.

Comment: thank you so much. But could you tell me  how gsub("[^[:digit:]]" works? Because my real data's name is like `$`NC_003070.9:c710954-710802 Arabidopsis thaliana chromosome 1 sequence.3`

Comment: @Codezy That is a completely different pattern. I have made the regular expression more to the point. It gets the last digits, after a period, `"\\."` and before the  end of string `"$"`.

Comment: You are the best my friend. Thank you so much this code perfectly solve my problem. But I dont understand how it works. Could you tell me how it works?

Comment: @Codezy See the explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your patiently answer thank you. Have a nice day : )

Answer (score 3):

You can use `purrr::transpose` after splitting.

Note: This code only works if you have the `purrr` package installed.

```
purrr::transpose(Map(split, list1, ca))
# $`1`
# $`1`[[1]]
# [1] "apple"   "account"
# 
# $`1`[[2]]
# [1] "tab"   "cable"
# 
# 
# $`2`
# $`2`[[1]]
# [1] "appreciate" "adapt"     
# 
# $`2`[[2]]
# [1] "tatabox"
# 
# 
# $`3`
# $`3`[[1]]
# [1] "available"
# 
# $`3`[[2]]
# [1] "banana"
```

For the updated example:

```
data1 <- c("apple","appreciate","available","account","adapt") 
data2 <- c("tab","banana","cable","tatabox","aaaaaaa") 
list1 <- list(data1,data2) 
ca <- lapply(list1, function(x) str_count(x, "a"))
```

you could use :

```
lapply(unique(unlist(ca)), 
       function(i) lapply(m, `[[`, as.character(i)))

# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1] "apple"   "account"
# 
# [[1]][[2]]
# [1] "tab"   "cable"
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1] "appreciate" "adapt"     
# 
# [[2]][[2]]
# [1] "tatabox"
# 
# 
# [[3]]
# [[3]][[1]]
# [1] "available"
# 
# [[3]][[2]]
# [1] "banana"
# 
# 
# [[4]]
# [[4]][[1]]
# NULL
# 
# [[4]][[2]]
# [1] "aaaaaaa"
```

Comment: Thank you Ryan but I am not totally understand this code. Is Map(split, list1, ca)  means use split to grouping list1 into different group by the number of ca?

Comment: That's right. `Map` applies the function given in the first argument to the first elements of all the other arguments, then the second element of all the other arguments, etc. So it gives `split(list1[[1]], ca[[1]])`, `split(list1[[2], ca[[2]])`. Then transpose groups all the first elements of the output together, all the second elements, etc.

Comment: Hi @Ryan but when I can to run a more complicate data, there is something goes wrong. data1 <- c("apple","appreciate","available","account","adapt")
data2 <- c("tab","banana","cable","tatabox","aaaaaaa")
list1 <- list(data1,data2) Please try this one and then you will find "aaaaaaa" will miss. Could you tell me how can I solve this problem?